# Apache Spark for business process?

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, bigdata

I understand the Big Data capabilities of Spark/Hadoop, but I'm being asked to use them for a set of processes that seem to not really fit into that, and I need a sanity check.

The processes are parallel at a high level, but contain inherently sequential independent sub-processes, that cannot be parallelized. A an example of this is X parallel top processes that kick off. Each one uses a different configuration to run a set of somewhat independent sub-processes:

- Download  set of XML (Sequentially)
- Validate each XML (Sequentially)
- Lightly process each XML (Sequentially)
- Load into a data store (Sequentially)

The processing contains *some* transformation but not much in big data terms. That processing is the one step that might benefit, but it still must be done sequentially for one flow.

This doesn't quite seem big-data-ish to me. In fact, it seems it might be a complete mis-use of that platform. The only benefit in this case might be consolidation of multiple platforms for support purposes, but in general the spark/hadoop ecosystem offers no gain for that sort of business-y process, right?

Or am I the crazy one?

Comment: I personally would try Apache NiFi for this rather than writing Spark code

Comment: Yea I've looked at NiFi, and am still investigating it. The real thing I'm looking for there is a robust API and SDK. We can't sell the UI of another tool, because it won't be customer demands. So at best we would build our own UI and use an underlying platform as the engine. So any tool that emphasizes its own UI is out of the running. I've yet to determine if Nifi fits the bill yet.

Comment: NiFi has a REST API to create Processors and Groups - https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/rest-api/index.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To me it sounds like your question really depends on:

1. the scale of the data
2. if you really cant do it in parallel (loading and validating xml sounds like something parallel but you know better then me
3. if all the process needs to be performed each time or do parts of it need to be performed a single time.

what I mean is : if a big chunk of the process is sequential (and needs to be run for each spark job and not once) and the bottleneck lies there then it sounds like you are correct and the start up time + complexity of Spark are good reasons to not use it.
But if you are asked to use Spark maybe there's a good reason for that.

Comment: The scale is not big-data large, but it's large. The reason its sequential is that the processing of one record depends on the value of some of the prior records. Theoretically it could be _stored_ in parallel, but then there would still be a post-process to perform those calculations, which means another platform or set of logic.

Comment: Okay now the main questions are , does the sequential process needs to run for each spark job or is it something that needs to be ran once and the processing on it woill performed multiple times.
and how long do you think the process will take without spark? if its less then 30 min then there is really no reason to do it.
in the end of the day in work enviroment if you are required to do something, you can always do in both ways and prove your way is a lot better.

Comment: The sequential process needs to run across the entire data set. E.g. it's a set of incremental XML files. The processing logic needs to process file X before processing file X+1.

Comment: After thinking about it some more, I might be able stream the data in to a big-data staging area _without_ processing it. And then run a post-process on that area that transforms and moves to data to a publishing layer. The post-process still has to be sequential, but the streaming process can be in whatever order the data arrives.


The staging area is still relational and operational for some consumers, it's just not transformed for more demanding consumers.